# Redirect syslog facility log to custom file

Tags: c++, logging, embedded, syslog, busybox

I have an embedded system with busy box in it. Busy box manual page states that:

> "Note that this version of syslogd ignores /etc/syslog.conf."

There is an option -O, but it redirects all messages to custom file.
I`m sending messages from C++. 
Found somewhere option -f for settings external config file - does not work.

That is how I connect to logger from my application:

```
    bool Log::start()
{
/* Launch process here */
    setlogmask(LOG_UPTO (LOG_DEBUG));
    openlog(LOG_IDENTITY, LOG_CONS | LOG_PID | LOG_NDELAY, LOG_LOCAL1);

    return true;
}
```

Can different log location for certain facility or facility mask for whole syslog by calling functions from my application? Or somehow?

Comment: It sounds like you have a fairly minimal syslogd implementation, so one approach could be to see if its code is concise enough that you can figure out what it is able to do by reading the source.  If you don't find what you need, options would seem to include using a different implementation, patching this one, or using an entirely different method to log to a file.

Answer (score 0):

We faced this same problem (not Busybox, but redirecting an application's syslog to a different log file using the bare-bones syslogd). The solution is two steps:

1. Update the application's call to openlog() to set the 3rd parameter to `int facility` and then create the configuration code that converts LOCAL0 through LOCAL7 into the LOG_LOCAL0 through LOG_LOCAL7 labels. Then we configure the application to specify LOCAL3 for those hosts where only that application's log data is needed.
2. Then our Operations folks are working to configure syslogd to redirect the log data for the LOCAL3 facility to a separate file. I don't know exactly what they have come up with, so I won't speculate further. But they had asked me to configure the facility in the knowledge that they can redirect syslogd output based on the facility.

One thing that I noticed is that you use `LOG_CONS`. I used to do that, but found that when syslogd could not be written to, this caused syslog to fork a child process and the Solaris x86_64 process table filled with zombies. So I don't use that flag anymore.